# Escaping commas in batch file START command?

Tags: batch-file, cmd

My below .bat file creates an email to be sent by Mozilla Thunderbird email client. I can't get the commas in the subject= to show up. The cmd line interprets commas literally to mean the end of the subject part. How can I escape them?

I have tried double quotes around the commas.
Tried ^,
Tried \,
Tried \,
Tried ','

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
start "" "C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Thunderbird\thunderbird.exe" -compose to=abc123@abc.com,subject=test, this comma, subject
EXIT
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
start "" "C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Thunderbird\thunderbird.exe" -compose "to='abc123@abc.com',subject='test, this comma, subject'"
```

use `"` at the beginning and end of the -compose argument.

use `'` at the beginning and end of sub arguments.

Answer (score 4):

use ' for quoting the subject

`start "" "C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Thunderbird\thunderbird.exe" -compose to=abc123@abc.com,subject='test, this comma, subject'`

Comment: Thank you as well, you both seemed to answer at the same time, I gave it to user93353 because he went a little more in depth, so it probably took him longer to type the question, so he probably started answering the question first. If I could choose both as correct answer I would!